# Java 3D game: Door opens too fast

Tags: java, 3d

I'm currently making a 2.5D FPS game in Java. My problem is that the doors open too fast when the player interacts with them. I have tried multiple methods like using a timer but everytime the door is instantly becomes fully open. How can I implement a smooth transition between a closed and an open state?

Here is my Door class:

```
public class DoorBlock extends SolidBlock {

    public boolean open = false;
    public double openness = 0;
    public double openLimit = 0.875;

    public static boolean useDoor = false;
    public int doorTimer = 0;

    public DoorBlock() {
        tex = 1;
    }

    public void tick() {
        super.tick();

        if (open)
            openness += 0.2;
        else
            openness -= 0.2;
        if (openness < 0)
            openness -= openness;
        if (openness > 1)
            openness = 1;

        if (openness < openLimit)
            blocksMotion = true;
        else
            blocksMotion = false;
    }

    //If the player opens the door
    public boolean use(StructureLoader level, Item item) {
        openness = openLimit;
        return true;
    }


    public boolean blocks(Entity entity) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `tick` work based on time, or just as fast as possible?

Comment: Yes, its based on time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the door to open instantly here

```
//If the player opens the door
public boolean use(StructureLoader level, Item item) {
    openness = openLimit;
    return true;
}
```

Modify it to trigger the opening mechanism in the tick function:

```
//If the player opens the door
public boolean use(StructureLoader level, Item item) {
    open = true;
    return true;
}
```